# Text and Icon in Android tablayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am trying to achieve this

[image: TabLayout]

I have constructed the tablayout but couldn't find a good way to add icons before the text in the left hand side.

[image: Current Tablayout]

I have tried .setIcon() but the icons is placed above the text.

**Note:**
I am using com.android.support:design:25.1.1'

Comment: If you want set icon and text in same line then it will help you [Click Here to set icon and text in Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749792/changing-tablayout-icons-on-left-top-right-or-bottom-in-com-android-supportde)

Answer (score 2):

you have to `setIcon` for Tab in `TabLayout`. follow the following link 
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: Thats the best example available on internet

Comment: I have tried but because of android support design 23.1.0 using setIcon sets the icon above the text

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to set icon to left of text

```
   private void setupTabIcons() {
        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setText(R.string.order_detail);
           tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.youricon, 0, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabTwo.setText(R.string.payment_status);
          tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.youricon, 0, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

        TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabThree.setText(R.string.locate_customer);
           tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.youricon, 0, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);

        TextView tabFour = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabFour.setText(R.string.call_customer);
           tabFour.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.youricon, 0, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(tabFour);

    }
```

and custom_tab.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this creat a custom_tab layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

**now set tab icon and tab title as per your requirement**

```
 TextView tvHome = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tvHome.setText("Home");
    tvHome.setTextSize(13);
    tvHome.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    tvHome.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawble.ic_icon, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tvHome);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setCustomView` on the `Tablayout` and apply your desired layout

Here is an [Example](https://mobikul.com/make-custom-tabs-icons-android/)

In code:

```
private void createTabIcons() {

    TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabOne.setText("Tab 1");
    tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_dash26, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
}
```

in your `layout/custom_tab`

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="@dimen/tab_label"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Hello Welcome to stack overflow ..if the answer helps mark it as correct by clicking the tick sign on left of the answer..

Answer (score 0):

There are tow way to Achieve that.

First way You need to create Separate xml layout(with TextView and ImageView as per your requirement) for that and set that to the layout. Like this

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_custom));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.tab_layout_custom));
```

Now you can set different name and tab layout text like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            View tab = ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(i);
            TextView textView = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.textView);
           ImageView imgView = (ImageView) tab.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                if (i == 0) {
                    textView.setText("TAB 1");
                   imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    textView.setText("TAB 2");
                  imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);                
  }

}
```

Second way is, see this [tutorials](https://mobikul.com/make-custom-tabs-icons-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is a much simpler way to achieve this by setting the `app:tabInlineLabel` attribute to `true`. Then, all you have to do is just set the icon like this:

```
tab.setIcon(yourIcon);
```